# What did the compiler and run-time system really do in my generated assembly?

Tags: objective-c, compiler-construction, runtime

I would like to understand how the generated assembly and the runtime work together, and came across a question while stepping through some generated assembly code.

**Source Example**

Here are three lines of Objective-C, running in XCode 4.5:

```
// Line 1:
NSObject *obj1 = [[NSObject alloc] init];

// Line 2:
[obj1 release];

// Line 3:
NSObject *obj2;
```

**Comparing the Generated Assembly**

Stepping through the generated assembly, I made a few observations.

Before line 1, the address of `obj1` is as shown:

```
obj1    (NSObject*) 0x00003604
```

After line 1, it changes:

```
obj1    NSObject *  0x08122110
```

**Observations**

1) The address of `obj1` was changed. When the source code is compiled, the compiler allocates temporarily memory for `obj1`. Then, (after line 1) the compiler apparently re-allocates, so the object's address changes.

2) After line 2, the address of `obj2` is still the same (`0x08122110`)! When I call `[obj1 release]`, I am telling the compiler: "I don't need this anymore. Please take it away." But the system is actually doing the release at some point in the future and I can not seem to control it directly.

3) The debugger can't step over line 3. I don't understand why it won't!

**Question**

In terms of creating and destroying objects, what is the compiler actually doing with these lines of code (specifically an "alloc-init", a release, and an NSObject pointer declaration without an assignment)? Also, why won't the debugger let me step over the third line? Can the debugger not see it?

Along with an answer, if you can please recommend some documents or a book about what the compiler and run-time system really do, I would appreciate it. Thank you very much!

Comment: Not sure why this was closed.  "Why won't the debugger let me step over this line" is, in and of itself, a tripping point for many new developers.  Understanding "expression that does something" vs. "this line is there purely for your [the developer's] convenience and doesn't really do much at all" is quite useful.  And the general "what the heck does the compiler do with this and how does it interact with the runtime" is also quite interesting, though the details are typically not needed by most devs most of the time.

Comment: I can't still understand why I can't step over line 3 ^^

Comment: Because line 3 is not a statement (“do this”), it is a declaration (“this exists”). Stepping goes between statements. A declaration with an initializer, like line 1, is close enough for the purpose of stepping, because the initializer is something to do—at the very least, putting something into the variable, and your initializer in line 1 also creates the object that it puts there.

Answer (score 12):

1. The pointer called `obj1` is created on the stack. It is not initialized which means that it will contain anything that was in that memory location. This is a constant source of bugs since using an uninitialized pointer can lead to unspecified behavior. Once the object is allocated the pointer is initialized with its address.
2. The address does not change because the pointer is not updated. When the `-release` message is sent to the object the retain counter is usually reduced by one. If the retain counter is already at one the `-dealloc` method is called and the memory is marked as free. Only the memory that the pointer points to is marked as free, but the pointer remains the same. That's why some prefer to also set their pointers to `nil` once they don't need them anymore.
3. You're creating an uninitialized pointer. Since it's not initialized it will reuse the data that was already at the memory location where the pointer is stored.

About the book recommendation. I would recommend *Compilers: Principles, Techniques, and Tools*.

Comment: I'm sorry, I wanted to write `NSObject *obj2` at line 3

Comment: And I wanted to mention the compiler and run-time system which Apple (XCode) used !

Comment: Note that ARC will ensure that all object reference variables are initialized to nil.

Answer (score 12):

Marcus's answer is quite good, but here are some more details (I'd been meaning to brush up reading generated assembly; having to actually try and explain it is the best way).

```
NSObject *obj1 = [[NSObject alloc] init]; // Line 1
```

The compiler compiles two function calls to `objc_msgSend()`.  The first calls the `+alloc` method on the `NSObject` class.   The result of that function call becomes the first argument -- the target object -- of the second function call which calls the method `-init`.

The result of calling `init` is then stored on the stack in a chunk of memory you have declared as being named `obj1` which has type of *a pointer to an instance of NSObject*.

You can step through this line in the debugger *because there is an executed expression on the line*.   If the code were written as:

```
NSObject *obj1; // declaration
obj1 = [[NSObject alloc] init];
```

Then you would find that you can't step through declaration.

Before `obj1 = [[NSObject alloc] init];, the value of`obj1`is *undefined* under Manual Retain Release, but **will be automatically set to`nil` (0) under ARC** (thereby eliminating the source of bugs Marcus indicated).

```
[obj1 release]; // Line 2
```

This line invokes the `release` method on the *instance of NSObject pointed to* by `obj1`.

```
NSObject *obj2; // Line 3
```

This line effectively does nothing.   If the compiler's optimizer were turned on, there would be no code generated at all.  Without the optimizer, the compiler *may* bump the stack pointer by `sizeof(NSObject*)` to reserve space on the stack with the name `obj2`.

And, again, you can't step through it in the debugger because there is no expression to execute on that line.

---

Of note, you could rewrite the code as:

```
[[[NSObject alloc] init] release];
```

That would be effectively identical to the original code you wrote as far as execution is concerned.  Without the optimizer, it will be a little bit different in that it won't store anything on the stack.  With the optimizer, it is likely to generate identical code as to your original code.  The optimizer is quite good at eliminating local variables when they aren't needed (which is also partially why debugging optimized code is so hard).

---

Given this:

```
(11) void f()
(12) {
(13)    NSObject *obj1 = [[NSObject alloc] init]; // Line 1
(14)    
(15)    [obj1 release]; // Line 2
(16)    
(17)    NSObject *obj2; // Line 3
(18)}
```

This is the unoptimized x86_64 assembly.  Ignore the "fixup" stuff.  Look at the `callq` lines;  they are the actual calls to objc_msgSend() as described above.  On x86_64, %rdi -- a register -- is argument 0 for all function calls.  Thus, %rdi is where the target of method calls goes.   %rax is the register used for return values.

So, when you see a callq, followed by `movq %rax, %rdi`, followed by another callq, that says "take the return value of the first `callq` and pass it as the first argument to the next `callq`.

As for your variables, you'll see things like `movq %rax, -8(%rbp)` after the `callq`.  This says "take whatever was returned by the `callq`, write it to the current spot on the stack, then move the stack pointer down 8 locations (the stack grows down)".    Unfortunately, the assembly doesn't show you the variable names.

```
_f:                                     ## @f
    .cfi_startproc
Lfunc_begin0:
    .loc    1 12 0                  ## /tmp/asdfafsd/asdfafsd/main.m:12:0
## BB#0:
    pushq   %rbp
Ltmp2:
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
Ltmp3:
    .cfi_offset %rbp, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
Ltmp4:
    .cfi_def_cfa_register %rbp
    subq    $32, %rsp
    leaq    l_objc_msgSend_fixup_release(%rip), %rax
    leaq    l_objc_msgSend_fixup_alloc(%rip), %rcx
    .loc    1 13 0 prologue_end     ## /tmp/asdfafsd/asdfafsd/main.m:13:0
Ltmp5:
    movq    L_OBJC_CLASSLIST_REFERENCES_$_(%rip), %rdx
    movq    %rdx, %rdi
    movq    %rcx, %rsi
    movq    %rax, -24(%rbp)         ## 8-byte Spill
    callq   *l_objc_msgSend_fixup_alloc(%rip)
    movq    L_OBJC_SELECTOR_REFERENCES_(%rip), %rsi
    movq    %rax, %rdi
    callq   _objc_msgSend
    movq    %rax, -8(%rbp)
    .loc    1 15 0                  ## /tmp/asdfafsd/asdfafsd/main.m:15:0
    movq    -8(%rbp), %rax
    movq    %rax, %rdi
    movq    -24(%rbp), %rsi         ## 8-byte Reload
    callq   *l_objc_msgSend_fixup_release(%rip)
    .loc    1 18 0                  ## /tmp/asdfafsd/asdfafsd/main.m:18:0
    addq    $32, %rsp
    popq    %rbp
    ret
Ltmp6:
Lfunc_end0:
```

---

For giggles, have a look at the assembly generated with the optimizer turned on (-Os -- fastest, smallest, the default for deployed code):

The first thing to note -- and this gets back to question (3) -- is that **there is no manipulation of `%rbp` outside of the very first and very last instructions.**   That is, nothing is pushed onto or pulled off the stack;  quite literally, there is no evidence that `obj1` and `obj2` were ever declared because the compiler didn't need them to generate equivalent code.

Everything is done via registers and you'll note that there is two `move %rax, %rdi`.  The first is "take the result of the `+alloc` and use it as the first argument to the call to `-init`" and the second is "take the result of the `-init` and use it as an argument to `-release`.

Aside;  `%rsi` is where the second argument to function calls resides on x86_64.   For method calls -- for calls to the `objc_msgSend()` function -- that argument will always contain the name of the method (the selector) to be called.

```
Lfunc_begin0:
    .loc    1 12 0                  ## /tmp/asdfafsd/asdfafsd/main.m:12:0
## BB#0:
    pushq   %rbp
Ltmp2:
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
Ltmp3:
    .cfi_offset %rbp, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
Ltmp4:
    .cfi_def_cfa_register %rbp
    .loc    1 13 0 prologue_end     ## /tmp/asdfafsd/asdfafsd/main.m:13:0
Ltmp5:
    movq    L_OBJC_CLASSLIST_REFERENCES_$_(%rip), %rdi
    leaq    l_objc_msgSend_fixup_alloc(%rip), %rsi
    callq   *l_objc_msgSend_fixup_alloc(%rip)
    movq    L_OBJC_SELECTOR_REFERENCES_(%rip), %rsi
    movq    %rax, %rdi
    callq   *_objc_msgSend@GOTPCREL(%rip)
    .loc    1 15 0                  ## /tmp/asdfafsd/asdfafsd/main.m:15:0
    leaq    l_objc_msgSend_fixup_release(%rip), %rsi
    movq    l_objc_msgSend_fixup_release(%rip), %rcx
    movq    %rax, %rdi
    popq    %rbp
    jmpq    *%rcx  # TAILCALL
Ltmp6:
Lfunc_end0:
```

---

If you want to learn even more about method dispatch, I wrote a [bit of a guide](http://www.friday.com/bbum/2009/12/18/objc_msgsend-part-1-the-road-map/).  It is a couple of versions of objc_msgSend() out of date, but still relevant.

Note that ARM code works the same way philosophically, but the generated assembly will be a bit different and quite a bit more of it.

---

> I can't still understand why I can't step over line 3 ^^

If you look at the generated assembly, there is nothing generated for the variable declarations.  At least not directly.   The closest would be `movq    %rax, -8(%rbp)`
 which moves the result of the `init` into , but that is *after the two function calls*.

For `NSObject *obj2;`, the compiler doesn't generate any code. Not even with the optimizer disabled.

That is because a variable declaration is not an expression;  it doesn't actually do anything other than provide a label for you -- the developer -- to use to hold values.   It is only when you actually use the variable that there is code generated.

Thus, when you are stepping in the debugger, it skips that line because there is nothing to do.

Comment: "You can step through this line in the debugger because there is an executed expression on the line"
I don't understand this ! What is an executed expression ?

Comment: Added a clarification at the end.

Comment: You said that "it skips that line because there is nothing to do". So,  debugger still stepped over if I just wrote `{}`. I think `{}` that also don't really do anything

Comment: I just had a look;  `{}` doesn't really do much of anything either.  The debugger skipped it, too, but it may be highly architecture specific (and possibly compiler specific).  Also keep in mind that the debugger may behave differently depending on whether the "do nothing" is at the end of the surrounding scope or in the middle.  The source level debugger is, more or less, a good approximation of what is going on at the execution level, but there is stuff skipped.  Mostly, the boilerplate bits that fall out of the language and ABI specifications.